# How to model Relationship with attributes between two models of the same meaning in mongo nicely?

Tags: mongodb

We have two crops.
1. Scenario
The Crop model looks like this:

```
{ 
  name: String,
  relationships: CropRelationship 
}
```

The CropRelationship model would look like this

```
{
  crop1: Crop,
  crop2: Crop,
  description: String,
  compatibility: Integer
}
```

But actually we would like to write code like:
tomato.relationship.crop.name # should print basil

As we don't know if tomato is in crop1 or crop2 this needs a function but isn't there a nicer way to do that?

2. Scenario
   We thought also about:
   Crop model:
   { 
     name: String,
     relationships: [Crop] 
   }

And then have a global list of CropRelationships and ask for the Relationships with a function of the two crops.

```
getCropRelationship(Crop,Crop.relationships[id])
```

3. Scenario
   Or our CropRelationship has only the other crop:

   {
       score: Integer
       description: String
       relatedCrop: Crop
    }

So then we could write

```
 tomato.relationships[id].relatedCrop.name
```

but all the relationship data would be doubled.

Any better suggestions?